# How to set momentLocalizer (moment.js) for react-big-calendar (fullcalendar.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using [react-big-calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar)
And need help to implement localization which is required
The example from git

```
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

BigCalendar.setLocalizer(
  BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment)
);
```

My code

```
var moment = require('moment');
var momentLocalizer = require('react-widgets/lib/localizers/moment');
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';

BigCalendar.setLocalizer(
    BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment.locale('en'))
);

let MyCalendar = props => (
    <div>
        <BigCalendar

        />
    </div>
);
```

Whatever I tried it doesn't work

> Uncaught TypeError: moment is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My code below, it works for me. I simply set the `culture` prop on my BigCalendar if I want to change localization.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);

class Calendar extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <BigCalendar
            culture='en-GB'
            events={this.props.tasks}
            views={['month', 'week']}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: cldr-data and globalize... that what i had to install. thanks for your help

Comment: I have a similar question: I want my BigCalendar in English but in custom TimeZone, not Europe/London. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 11):

I had to import the locale I wanted to get the calendar in the correct locale.

Notice the `import 'moment/locale/nb';`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/nb';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

BigCalendar.setLocalizer(BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment));

class Calendar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      events: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Calendar">
        <BigCalendar
          events={this.state.events}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is for version 0.17.0 of *react-big-calendar*.