# How to change time format in react-big-calendar.I want to remove "00" from time bar

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I want to remove "00" from time in react-big-calendar but not able to find the way.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you had looked into [Localization and Date Formatting](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar#localization-and-date-formatting) in the Readme / Manual, you could have easily done it using the following. TBH, it's right there in the [Getting Started](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#intro) - you need to use `dateFormat`:

```js
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment'

// Setup the localizer by providing the moment (or globalize) Object
// to the correct localizer.
const localizer = BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment) // or globalizeLocalizer

const MyCalendar = props => (
  <div>
    <BigCalendar
      localizer={localizer}
      events={myEventsList}
      startAccessor="start"
      endAccessor="end"
      dateFormat="h t"
    />
  </div>
)
```

**Preview**

[image: demo]

Related: [How to set momentLocalizer (moment.js) for react-big-calendar (fullcalendar.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36514480)